# How to negate a string in regex

Tags: regex

I know three things...

1) I know that:

```
a.{1,250}?z
```

Will check that a is within 250 characters of z.

2) I know that

```
a[^b]{1,250}?z
```

Will check that a is within 250 characters of z, but that none of those characters are b.

3) I also know that

```
a[^bad]{1,250}?z
```

Will check that a is within 250 characters of z, but that none of those characters are b, a, or d.

**but**

4)

How wow would I check that a occurs within 250 characters of z, but that the word bad does not appear between them?

Imagining "string" required an exact match (like in a google search) the pseudo-code would look like:

```
a[^"bad"]{1,250}?z
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple, use a negative lookahead.

```
a(?:(?!bad).){1,250}?z
```

`(?:(?!bad).)` would match any character (except line breaks) but not of the substring `bad`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nI6uL1/3)

And also you must use anchors or word boundaries in-order to do an exact match or otherwise, the above regex would match `adccz` for this `acbadccz` input.

```
\ba(?:(?!bad).){1,250}?z\b
```

Comment: Not exactly *regular* (lookaheads are an extension), but I'm not sure this can be technically solved with pure regular expressions... So you get +1 from me :)

Comment: @Seb, negative lookahead can be solved completely with a plain regular expression, but in general, a regular expression that matches the exact set of strings is much more complicated than the original one.  That's the reason of extending.  It's easy to demonstrate with finite automata, but outside the time and the space here to do.

Comment: just a quicknote , I tried using this in my expression and it didn't work correctly as is was - > (?:(?!bad).) so I tried changing it to -> (?:(?!bad).*) and worked well as far as I tested it with a couple of examples